# Can you put an if statement within an until loop?

Tags: bash, scripting

We have to make a script with one `until` loop to repeatedly ask 
the user for a number. 
- If the number is not 50, display the message, “Wrong number; try again.”
- ask for another number. 
- If the number is 50, display the message, “You got it!” and stop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    echo -n "please choose a number: "
    read number
    until [$number -eq 50];
    do
         if [$number !=50]
         then 
               echo "Wrong number; try again" 
               read wrong 
         else 
               echo -n "Please choose a number: "
               read newnum
         fi
    done
```

I'm not sure how to loop the "Please choose a number" statement. I always end up with the error:

```
      syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'
```

I've been looking online, but there are no clear examples of input output UNTIL loops

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: Yeah you can, probably.

Comment: You have many problems with your script: missing space around arguments of `[ ... ]` constructs, you wrote `number` to get the value of the variable instead of `$number`, you use a different variable name later `newnum` instead of `number`, you don't put double quotes around tests like so: `"$number"`. You need to follow a shell scripting tutorial

Comment: I input my code that I tried running. I'm sorry I'm a beginner at Shell Scripting.

Comment: @Celada I'm not sure where to begin. The examples my professor showed us do not look at all like what we're supposed to be doing. Do you know of any shell scripting tutorial I can see? I've been looking at all the ones that contain UNTIL loops.

Comment: You are also using `elif` where `else` should be used and you are not following the "You got it!" message and `exit` instruction.

Comment: Thank you @jlliagre! What do you mean the exit instruction? I don't understand why the script does not understand the number 50. Is the number 50 supposed to be in quotes? It says
     "line 10: [50: command not found" Line 10 is where "until [$number -eq 50]" is

Comment: What do I mean the exit instruction: `"If the number is 50, display the message, “You got it!” and stop."` Why the script doesn't understand the number 50: read closer comment #3 `missing space around arguments of [ ... ] constructs`

Comment: What jlliagre means is that there's nothing in your program that prints `You got it!` when the correct number (50) is read. That error in line 10 is happening because you don't have a space after the `[`. So if number equals 50, bash sees ` [number ` as `[50` and thinks that it's a command, which it tries to run. Do you _have_ to use an `until` loop for this program, or is some other control structure allowed?

Comment: [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is full of _excellent_ info about Bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo -n "please choose a number: "

read number
until [ $number -eq 50 ]
do
     # if [ $number -ne 50 ]
     # then 
           echo "Wrong number; try again" 
           read number 
     # fi
done 

echo You got it\!
```

The first `read` reads into variable `number`. The `until` loop loops until `$number` equals 50.

The test inside the loop is unnecessary , since the `until` only enters when the number is `-ne` (not equal to) 50.

The main problem you had was that `read` inside the loop must update the same variable (`number`) as the `until` construct checks.

The spacing is important too, because the word (surrounded by whitespace) after `if` is the name of a command. `[$number` evaluates to whatever was inputed, but prefixed by '[', which is most likely not the name of an existing command. For instance, if the first guess was `42`, the `if` command would try to execute the command `[42`, causing an error like **`[42: not found`**.

Also, comparing numbers is done with `-eq`, `-lt`, `-ge`, `-gt`, `-ge`, `-ne`.

`=` and `=!` are for strings.

Comment: Let me to advise remove 1st `read` (3rd line) - insid'e the loop is enough if you remain `if` for `echo "Wrong..."`.

Comment: @Costas: I think having the extra `read` statement outside the loop is cleaner than testing number twice per loop.

Comment: @MattBianco: You should put `"` around `$number` - it makes the error message nicer if the user enters the empty string or a string containing more than one word. Also, if you put `"` around the final echo arg you don't need to escape the `!`

Answer (score 0):

In the other answer you got some more general advise on your program, so I will point you to the actual mistake, which is in the line with the `if`

```
if [$number !=50]
```

It should be:

```
if [ $number -ne 50 ]
```

I changed three things here

- I replaced `!=` with `-ne`. The first one is invalid
- I added a space between `[` and `$number`. (Check by correcting the first step what happens if you don't).

Of course you get a weird program with unexpected behavior, but it'll run :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while :; do
    read -p "Please choose a number: " number
    [ "$number" -eq 50 ] 2>/dev/null
    case $? in
        0) break ;;
        1) echo "Wrong number; try again." ;;
        2) echo "Not a valid number; try again." ;;
    esac
done

echo "You got it!"
```

Where `while` can be replaced with `until`, if desired. But I get the feeling that the professor would *not* be pleased if musicstrings submitted this program. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, concise.

```
read -p "please choose a number: " number

until ((number == 50)); do
    read -p "Wrong number; try again : " number
done

echo "You got it!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'* cannot be explained with the code you posted unless both `then` and `else` are followed by invisible characters like a CR character (as when files come from Microsoft OS where the line delimiter is CRLF instead of just LF. But then if it were a DOS formatted file, I'd expect other error messages because of the CR after `do` and `done`.

**Edit**: looking at the revision history of your question, the error seems to correspond to a mistake in a [prior version of your script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/168385/3).

You have a number of errors with your `[` command syntax, unquoted variables, as already noted, but I'd like to add that the syntax of an `until` loop is:

```
until
  condition-command-list
do
  action-command-list
done
```

The `condition-command-list` can be any number of commands like the `action-command-list`, so you can do

```
until
  printf 'please choose a number: '
  read number || [ -n "$number" ] || exit
  [ "$number" -eq 50 ]
do
  echo >&2 'Wrong number; try again'
done
```

The `|| exit` part is to exit the script upon EOF (otherwise it would loop forever if the script's stdout was closed as when you run `echo 49 | your-script`).